# Confirm Dialog not working

Tags: java, swing, conditional-statements

I am trying to make it so that after you play the game and determine the winner, it will ask if the user wants to play again. I added a "do while" loop but it doesn't seem to working. The output is always something along the lines of:

- Play the game
- Get the winner/loser/tie and score
- Ask what you want to choose again
- then ask if the user wants to play again
- even if the user says no, it doesn't stop the game

I'm not sure what the issue is as I am pretty new to coding. Thanks!

```
/*
Playing Rock Paper Scissors against a computer would be really boring if we 
always knew what the computer was going to choose, or we created a program 
that has a distinct pattern. In order to increase replayability of your game
you will want to randomize the computer's choice.

For our game we will have the computer generate a random number (0, 1, or 2) 
which will correspond to one of the choices (i.e. 0 = Rock, 1 = Paper, 2 = 
Scissors)  
 */

import javax.swing.*;
public class rockPaperScissors {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int playAgain = 0;
        int score = 0;
        String [] playerOptions = {"Rock","Paper","Scissor"};
        String playerChoice = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1, 2, 3, Shoot:",
                "Rock, Paper, Scissor",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,playerOptions,playerOptions[0]);//Gets players pick
        int computerChoice = (int)(Math.random()*(3));//gets computers choice randomly
        while (playerChoice.equals("Rock") || playerChoice.equals("Paper") || playerChoice.equals("Scissors")) {

            do {
                if (computerChoice == 0 && playerChoice.equals("Rock")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tied! You both chose rock.");//determines winner and prints only for tied and wins for user
                    System.out.println(score);

                    playerChoice = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1, 2, 3, Shoot:",
                            "Rock, Paper, Scissor",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,playerOptions,playerOptions[0]);
                } else if (computerChoice == 0 && playerChoice.equals("Paper")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You won!");

                    score = score+1;
                    System.out.println(score);

                    playerChoice = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1, 2, 3, Shoot:",
                            "Rock, Paper, Scissor",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,playerOptions,playerOptions[0]);
                } else if (computerChoice == 1 && playerChoice.equals("Paper")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tied! You both chose Paper!");
                    System.out.println(score);

                    playerChoice = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1, 2, 3, Shoot:",
                            "Rock, Paper, Scissor",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,playerOptions,playerOptions[0]);
                } else if (computerChoice == 1 && playerChoice.equals("Scissor")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You won!");
                    score = score+1;
                    System.out.println(score);

                    playerChoice = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1, 2, 3, Shoot:",
                            "Rock, Paper, Scissor",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,playerOptions,playerOptions[0]);
                } else if (computerChoice == 2 && playerChoice.equals("Scissor")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tied! You both chose scissor!");
                    System.out.println(score);

                    playerChoice = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1, 2, 3, Shoot:",
                            "Rock, Paper, Scissor",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,playerOptions,playerOptions[0]);
                } else if (computerChoice == 2 && playerChoice.equals("Rock")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You won!");
                    score = score+1;
                    System.out.println(score);

                    playerChoice = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1, 2, 3, Shoot:",
                            "Rock, Paper, Scissor",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,playerOptions,playerOptions[0]);
                } else { //if user lost 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You lost! Try again!");
                    score = score-1;
                    System.out.println(score);

                    playerChoice = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1, 2, 3, Shoot:",
                            "Rock, Paper, Scissor",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,playerOptions,playerOptions[0]);
                }
                playAgain = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Play again?");
            } while (playAgain == 0);
        }
        System.out.println("Game Ended");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are the wrong way around

```
while (playerChoice.equals("Rock") || playerChoice.equals("Paper") || /*...*/) 
{
    do {
        // did they win?
        // ...
        playAgain = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Play again?");
    } while (playAgain == 0);
}
```

You want to move the do-while loop around pretty much all of the game's logic e.g.

```
do {
    // get input and computer choice
    while (playerChoice.equals("Rock") || playerChoice.equals("Paper") || /*...*/)
    {
        // did they win?
        // ...
    }
    playAgain = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Play again?");
} while (playAgain == 0);
```

Comment: So I tried that but I'm not sure if I still did it right. It keeps giving me an error when I try to close the code with a bracket. `while (playAgain == 0){
    do {
   
    String playerChoice = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"1, 2, 3, Shoot:",
            "Rock, Paper, Scissor",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,playerOptions,playerOptions[0]);//Gets players pick
    int computerChoice = (int)(Math.random()*(3));//gets computers choice randomly
   
    while (playerChoice.equals("Rock") || playerChoice.equals("Paper") || playerChoice.equals("Scissors"))
    {`

Comment: Maybe edit your original question with the new code. I can't read that.